# How to pass data between 2 gRPC streaming servers in the same microservice?

Tags: go, stream, grpc, channel

I have a microservice with 2 gRPC servers, the first server (let's call it the collector server) collects logs from other services using the protobuf form `rpc GetLogs(stream LogMessage) returns (Dummy){}` and does some processing on `LogMessage` and then passes it to the other gRPC server (let' call it the broadcaster server), which is again is serving in the same microservice binary, which in turn broadcasts it to whatever client that wants to subscribe to the processed logs in the protobuf form `rpc GetLogs(Dummy) returns (stream ProcessedLogMessage){}`. AFAIK channels cannot simply work in this case since each running gRPC method of the second gRPC server lives in its own goroutine, so I cannot tell in compile time how many of these goroutines can be running in the same time

Comment: Could you not listen on 127.0.0.1:xxxx and have the service connect to itself?  If a single pos will always process its own messages, it would seem more appropriate to refactor it to perform both tasks to avoid the need for a connection, and marshelling/unmarshalling between the 2.

Comment: Assuming the clients of the broadcast service receives the messages arrived after the subscription of the client, you can have a mediator service with a defined buffer size (which can be 0) that reads messages from the first service and sends those to the subscribers of the second service.